# xcode edit file.txt with URL filepath

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a NSUrlRequest as filepath and I would to know how to add sentence in this file. This file is a txt file and is in the same folder like the .m
The code below, allow the generate an URL address and display the file in a WebView:

```
     NSURL *url = [self generateFileURL:self.documentName];
 NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Thanks,

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filehandle

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I look at your link but I do not understand all the focntions. Can you code me an example so that I understand? thank you.